# Keyword changes or new keyword add while updating app version in app store

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, keyword-search

Although its not a technical question however its kinda killing me as I am not getting a confirmed status from anyone. I have two apps in app store which has common features(One is free version and another is a paid one). When I submitted it, I added some keyword so that they will be searched when the user hits some special keyword. Now my client wants to add some keyword so that search will be relevant for this two app. My question is will apple allow me to add/change keywords if I will go and update the apps from version 1.0 to 1.1 (with minor bug fix)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can change the keywords as part of an app update. It doesn't matter how minor or major the update is. If you read the "iTunes Connect Developer Guide", it covers what about can be changed and when.

Comment: Thats right. However some people says its a Locked property so I thought I should make a confirmation first before the proceedings. Thanks.